# Custom message for geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation, location

I am looking for a way in which i can display a custom message when the geolocation script asks for the user to either allow or deny access to their location.

At the moment it displays a message asking weather the user wants to allow or deny access to their location. Instead of it saying the default "Allow website.com to access your location" I want to be able to change it to my own text such as "Allow location access to display better results".

I will look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done. Otherwise a user may not know what it is that they might be agreeing to. There is no guarantee a custom message would need to even mention location at all.

Comment: It would be nice that you could add a custom message below or above the default message (which should be mandatory, for the reason you give). This way the user would know why the site is requesting location.